# Extract only first appearance of number after gsub

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a string like this:

```
Sample.ID<-"(<SampleID>, 2213 )"
```

I am using the following gsub code to extract the numbers from this string:

```
ID<-as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", Sample.ID))
```

This is ok, but sometimes in my data the string is like this:

```
Sample.ID<-"(<SampleID>, 2213-EQUINOX BELL 2-P, )"
```

Then I have a problem, as it take all number (i.e. 22132) where I just wanted to have 2213. 
What is the work-around?

Thanks,
Phuong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your data looks like

`Sample.ID<-"(<SampleID>, 2213-EQUINOX BELL 2-P, )"`

use `(?<=, )\d+` to match the number: [Regex-test](https://regex101.com/r/jE0lI9/1)

The following code match the whole string and extract the 1st group:

`gsub(".*(?<=, )(\\d+).*", "\\1", id, perl=TRUE)`

Check the snippet: [R-gsub](http://rextester.com/FUEBP93608)

Comment: Thank you very much for you all comments. All solutions worked well for me. Really appreciate!

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the digits and then use a backreference

```
sub(".*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", Sample.ID)
[1] "2213" "2213"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can match zero or more characters that are not a comma (`[^,]*`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by a `,`, one or more space (`\\s+`) or `|` a `-` or space followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
as.numeric(gsub("^[^,]*,\\s+|(-|\\s+).*", "", Sample.ID))
#[1] 2213 2213
```

---

If there are no other restrictions, then `str_extract` can be used to extract the first occurrence of number

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(Sample.ID, "\\d+"))
#[1] 2213 2213
```

Or with `parse_number` from `readr`

```
readr::parse_number(Sample.ID)
#[1] 2213 2213
```

Or a similar option with `base R`

```
as.numeric(regmatches(Sample.ID, regexpr("\\d+", Sample.ID)))
#[1] 2213 2213
```

#### data

```
Sample.ID <- c("(<SampleID>, 2213 )", "(<SampleID>, 2213-EQUINOX BELL 2-P, )")
```